# Rails "can't convert Spreadsheet::Workbook into String"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spreadsheet

I'm trying to use the spreadsheet gem in my Rails app, but I get the following error:

```
can't convert Spreadsheet::Workbook into String
```

This is my code:

```
require 'spreadsheet'

def create_spreadsheet_from_array(array)
   Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
   book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
   ...
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error you are seeing does not come from the brief snippet of code you provided. You need to provide more code. Also, look at the backtrace included with the exception to help find the line of code that is triggering this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess from your limited details is that your code trying to output the rendered spreadsheet file in a view template. You need to use send_file in your controller. Here is a simple example (but I don't really recommend having the spreadsheet code in the controller):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def download_xls
    filename = "example.xls"
    tempfile = Tempfile.new(filename)
    workbook = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
    ...
    workbook.write(tempfile.path)
    send_file tempfile.path, :filename => filename
  end
end
```